# Angular 7- ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: angular

I'm new to angular, and I'm trying to create new form screen with multiple checkboxes, I have the main table of "Roles" and "Permissions", and when creating new role, the user must choose permissions

I created a new form for the new role screen, also I created the permissions service, but when using map in order to create the form array, I get the error above

```
import { FormBuilder, FormArray } from '@angular/forms';
import { Injectable, ɵConsole } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Role } from '../model/role.model';
import { Permission } from '../model/permission.model';
import { Observable} from 'rxjs';
import { NewroleComponent } from '../Components/newrole/newrole.component';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { PermissionService } from './permission.service';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RoleService {
  private serviceUrl = 'https://adminfinal2.herokuapp.com/rolesonhp';
  httpOptions = { headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'})};
  permissions;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private permissionService: PermissionService, private formBuilder: FormBuilder  ) { 
    this.permissionService.getPermission().subscribe(results => {
      if (!results) {
        return;
      }
      console.log(results);
      //this.permissions = new FormArray(results);
      console.log(this.permissions);
    });
    const controls = this.permissions.map(c => new FormControl(false));
    controls[0].setValue(true); // Set the first checkbox to true (checked)

    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      permissions: new FormArray(controls)
    });
  }

  form: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    $key: new FormControl(null),
    roleName: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    description: new FormControl('',Validators.required),
    // permissions: new FormArray([ new FormControl(false)])
  });


  initializeFormGroup() {



    this.form.setValue({
      $key: null,
      roleName: '',
      description: '',
      controls:''
    });

  }
  populateForm(role) {
    // console.log('in service: ' + user.userName_gmail);
    this.form.setValue({
      $key: role.roleId,
      roleName: role.name,
      description: role.description,

    });
  }
  getRole(): Observable<Role[]> {
    return this.http.get<Role[]>(this.serviceUrl);
   }

   addRole(role): Observable<Role> {
    return this.http.post<Role>(this.serviceUrl, role, this.httpOptions);
   }
}
```

when printing the results(console.log(results);), I do see the values in the console.

Comment: subscribe is _asynchronous_. Assuming you are setting `this.permissions` from `results`.. it wont be set till the observable returns...So it will most likely be undefined outside

Answer (score 0):

I am suspecting till the API is resolved your **permissions** is undefined so the error is coming and console.log is getting executed because it inside the subscribe and getting executed after API is resolved.Putting the **permissions** inside the subscribe.

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient, private permissionService: PermissionService, private formBuilder: FormBuilder  ) { 
this.permissionService.getPermission().subscribe(results => {
  if (!results) {
    return;
  }
  console.log(results);
  //this.permissions = new FormArray(results);
  console.log(this.permissions);
   const controls = this.permissions.map(c => new FormControl(false));
controls[0].setValue(true); // Set the first checkbox to true (checked)

this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
  permissions: new FormArray(controls)
});
});
}
```